# Get unique key warning when add a key attribute to a div element with some sub nodes in it with react v18.2.0

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-key-index

The codes below will cause the warning: "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop." when I try to render the div element into the page.

```
<div {...{}} key={"formKey"}>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Test</button>
 </div>
```

And when I adjust my codes into the following, the warning won't appear.

```
<div key={"formKey"} {...{}}>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Test</button>
 </div>
```

It seems to be the order of the props that I passed to the div element, and the warning won't appear either when the div element only have at most one sub node. I just can't figure out the reason.

I just want to know the real reason which caused the different situations that I described, I just thouhgt that the order I passed props should never have different results.

Comment: Is that DIV being rendered from a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your bug

```js
const App = () => <div>
  <div {...{}} key={"formKey"}>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div {...{}} key={"formKey"}>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

However it might be because `"formKey"` is a constant string, not a variable different for each of your list element. You code should typically look like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => <ul>
  {
    users.map((user) => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)
  }
</ul>;
```

Comment: I didn't use cdn to import react to my application, and the react version that I use is 18.2.0. And I don't think it's a good idea to put both two divs with the same key into App, you will always get the key warning.

Comment: I just create a new react project with vite and it only contains a App component like this: `export default function App() {
  return (
    <div {...{}} key="fdsafdsaf">
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Test</button>
    </div>
  );
}`，and the warning will appear.